# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible

Tags: c#

Trying to make a money counter on C# and getting an error with an integer called costofcredit, i have declared this as an int I then have a button which i click and it will add 1p on and within this button i have the code of
costofcredit = Convert.ToInt32(textCPC);
and this is where i get the message below is my whole code

```
if (textCPC.Text != "0") 
            {
                onepence = onepence + 1
                label1p.Text = onepence.ToString(); 
                totalpence = totalpence + 1; 
                textTPV.Text = totalpence.ToString(); 
                totalpounds = totalpence / 100; 
                textTPVal.Text = totalpounds.ToString("n2"); 
                costofcredit = Convert.ToInt32(textCPC); 
                amountofcredits = Convert.ToInt32(totalpence) / costofcredit; 
                textAPC.Text = amountofcredits.ToString(); 
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter the cost per credit!"); 
            }
```

Comment: Change to Convert.ToInt32(textCPC.Text);

Comment: Hahaha.! Dude you changed whole question. You can't do that open a new thread if you have another problem and yes please be clear on questions also here nobody understands what problem you are facing because you haven't attached any code snippet or Screen Shot without that how one is supposed to understand where problem might be?

Comment: i cant dd another question for another 3 days so not waiting

Answer (score 2):

Because `textCPC` TextBox class did't implement`System.IConvertible` interface.

When you use `Convert.ToInt32` the object need to implement `System.IConvertible`

```
Convert.ToInt32(textCPC.Text);
```

instead of

```
Convert.ToInt32(textCPC);
```

Comment: Now getting System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' on cost of credit

Comment: What is your input data?

Comment: what is that sorry have little knowledge

Comment: @dave please see my answer, I provided information on how to use `System.Int32.TryParse()`

Comment: @dave I mean what's your `textCPC.Text` value

Comment: it has to be anything above 0 and if left blank an error messge should appear

Answer (score 0):

You are using `textCPC` which I believe is a TextBox. You need value of the TextBox so should use `textCPC.Text`.

Comment: Now getting System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' on cost of credit

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert the `textCPC` itself (which is a TextBox control) to an integer value while you should convert it's value by using `textCPC.Text`. So just change

```
Convert.ToInt32(textCPC);
```

To

```
Convert.ToInt32(textCPC.Text);
```

Try to use `[Int32.TryParse]`[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) so that when you input incorrect data it won't through an exception. Or just use it inside a `try/catch` statement.

Comment: Input data must be integer type.

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in the comments, you need to convert the `.Text` property of textCPC like so `Convert.ToInt32(textCPC.Text)` which if the `Value` of textbox textCPC is an integer value will work, seeing how you aren't using a try catch for exception handling you may want to use `System.Int32.TryParse` in case the user enters something non-integer:

```
//Declare an out parameter of type int
int outIntCheck = 0;

//Check to see if you can successfully parse an integer value
if(System.Int32.TryParse(textCPC.Text, out outIntCheck)
   costofcredit = outIntCheck;
else
   //Show incorrect integer format error
```

Comment: Documentation on `System.Int32.TryParse()` can be found here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: but ive already declared textcpc as textcostpercredit int at the top so why wont it work if ive already declared it

Comment: @dave what do you mean? I am not understanding what you are saying by "declared textcpc as textcostpercredit int at the top so why wont it work", for `System.Convert` to execute correctly, the string value inside your textbox must be a valid integer value like  "0", "1", "10" etc. if it is something like "abc" or "10.45", etc. those are not valid integer values and the Conversion will fail and throw an exception.

Comment: howdo i add a string value to my integer

Comment: @dave you convert the string to an integer and then set it to your costofcredit variable, My answer just takes into account user error where the value that is entered is not a valid integer. `System.Int32.TryParse()` takes the value it needs to try to parse as the first parameter and an integer variable that is set with the parsed value when it succeeds, the method itself returns boolean true or false, hence the if-else statement in my answer, if successful at parsing it sets costofcredit to the integer output variable outIntCheck, if it fails at parsing the textbox value show error.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

        TaskEmployee taskEmployee = new TaskEmployee();
        TaskEmployeeBLL taskEmployeeBLL = new TaskEmployeeBLL();
        Task1 task1 = new Task1();

        int employeeid = Convert.ToInt32(employeeNameShowComboBox.SelectedValue);

        bool save = false;

        foreach (ListViewItem itemRow in taskShowListView.Items)
        {

            if (itemRow.Selected == true)
            {
                int taskId = Convert.ToInt32(itemRow.SubItems[0].Text);
                string taskDate = itemRow.SubItems[1].ToString();
                string taskDescription = itemRow.SubItems[2].ToString();

                task1.TaskID = taskId;
                task1.TaskDate = taskDate;
                task1.TaskDescription = taskDescription;

                taskEmployee.EmployeeId = employeeid;
                save = taskEmployeeBLL.TaskEmployeeSaveShow(taskEmployee, task1);

            }

        }


        if (save)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("save success");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Don't save");
            return;
        }



    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.